# Golang, parsing xml to struct?

Tags: go, xml-parsing

I have such xml document and I need to get an array of DATA. I cannot solve this simple task for 4 hours.... want back to node.js :-)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<RETS ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="Operation Successful" >
<COUNT Records="58951" />
<DELIMITER value="09"/>
<COLUMNS>   LN  </COLUMNS>
<DATA>  09361303    </DATA>
<DATA>  09333085    </DATA>
<MAXROWS/>
```

```
type DATA struct {
    DATA string `xml:"DATA"`
}

type Rets struct {
    DATA []DATA `xml:"RETS>DATA"`
}


data := &Rets{}
decoder := xml.Unmarshal(body,&data)

fmt.Println(decoder)
```

Comment: `decoder` is the error returned by `xml.Unmarshal`, and you're passing a `**Rets` to `Unmarshal`, rather than a `*Rets`.

Comment: sorry, of course fmt.Println(data), but I got an empty object

Comment: However, number of elements are correct, but they are empty.

Comment: rdata := new(Rets)

 err = xml.Unmarshal(body, &rdata)
 fmt.Println(rdata)

&{[{} {} {} {} {}] However number of array elements are correct - maybe it is because of spaces in DATA elements?

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of tools for turning XML into Go structs. One that is suitable for reading is [zek](https://github.com/miku/zek/) (try it [online](https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/)), and although it is experimental, it can deal with a couple of common XML constructs already.

You can go from a [XML file](https://gist.github.com/miku/3df6ddbba9f7baf078662d682e8f32e0#file-rets-xml) ([raw](https://git.io/fN4Pq)) to a struct with a simple command:

```
$ curl -sL https://git.io/fN4Pq | zek -e -p -c
```

This will create a struct plus an [example program](https://gist.github.com/miku/3df6ddbba9f7baf078662d682e8f32e0#file-main-go) for testing out the marshalling (the example does very little, it read XML from stdin and turns it into [JSON](https://gist.github.com/miku/3df6ddbba9f7baf078662d682e8f32e0#file-readme-md)).

Here is an example struct (for some XML take from [this repo](https://github.com/estately/rets/blob/master/test/fixtures.rb)):

```
// RETS was generated 2018-09-07 12:11:10 by tir on apollo.local.
type RETS struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name `xml:"RETS"`
    Text          string   `xml:",chardata"`
    ReplyCode     string   `xml:"ReplyCode,attr"`
    ReplyText     string   `xml:"ReplyText,attr"`
    METADATATABLE struct {
        Text     string   `xml:",chardata"`
        Resource string   `xml:"Resource,attr"`
        Class    string   `xml:"Class,attr"`
        Version  string   `xml:"Version,attr"`
        Date     string   `xml:"Date,attr"`
        COLUMNS  string   `xml:"COLUMNS"` // MetadataEntryID    SystemNam...
        DATA     []string `xml:"DATA"`    // 7  City        City    Ci ...
    } `xml:"METADATA-TABLE"`
}
```

Disclaimer: I wrote zek.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`xml.Unmarshal` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal)

> - If the XML element contains character data, that data is
>     accumulated in the first struct field that has tag ",chardata".
>     The struct field may have type []byte or string.
>     If there is no such field, the character data is discarded.

Use

```
type DATA struct {
    DATA string `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Rets struct {
    DATA []DATA `xml:"DATA"`
}
```

Or in this simple case, you can just use

```
type Rets struct {
    DATA []string `xml:"DATA"`
}
```

Which collects the charadata from a list of elements by default

Comment: Wow, Jim. THANK YOU SOOO MUCH! I thought my attempt to switch to go  failed on step 1 :-)!

Comment: Great, both works. I do not understand fully where chardata came from but I will read docs more :-). Have a great day!