# Golang XML to Struct

Tags: go

I want to unmarshal this xml with golang, but I don't know how to define struct.

```
<ZIP_result>
    <result name="ZipSearchXML"/>
    <result version="1.01"/>
    <result request_url="http%3A%2F%2Fzip.cgis.biz%2Fxml%2Fzip.php%3Fzn%3D1310045"/>
    <result request_zip_num="1310045"/>
    <result request_zip_version="none"/>
    <result result_code="1"/>
    <result result_zip_num="1310045"/>
    <result result_zip_version="0"/>
    <result result_values_count="1"/>
    <ADDRESS_value>
        <value state_kana="トウキョウト"/>
        <value city_kana="スミダク"/>
        <value address_kana="オシアゲ"/>
        <value company_kana="none"/>
        <value state="東京都"/>
        <value city="墨田区"/>
        <value address="押上"/>
        <value company="none"/>
    </ADDRESS_value>
</ZIP_result>
```

Can anyone teach me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Golang, parsing xml to struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095427/golang-parsing-xml-to-struct)

Comment: https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/

Comment: @icza This is nice site! Thanks! I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you find this helpful.

```
package main


import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)


type ZIPResult struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ZIP_result"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Result  []Result `xml:"result"`
    ADDRESSValue Address `xml:"ADDRESS_value"`
}

type Result struct {
    Text              string `xml:",chardata"`
    Name              string `xml:"name,attr"`
    Version           string `xml:"version,attr"`
    RequestURL        string `xml:"request_url,attr"`
    RequestZipNum     string `xml:"request_zip_num,attr"`
    RequestZipVersion string `xml:"request_zip_version,attr"`
    ResultCode        string `xml:"result_code,attr"`
    ResultZipNum      string `xml:"result_zip_num,attr"`
    ResultZipVersion  string `xml:"result_zip_version,attr"`
    ResultValuesCount string `xml:"result_values_count,attr"`
}

type Address struct {
    Text  string `xml:",chardata"`
    Value []Value`xml:"value"`
}

type Value struct {
    Text        string `xml:",chardata"`
    StateKana   string `xml:"state_kana,attr"`
    CityKana    string `xml:"city_kana,attr"`
    AddressKana string `xml:"address_kana,attr"`
    CompanyKana string `xml:"company_kana,attr"`
    State       string `xml:"state,attr"`
    City        string `xml:"city,attr"`
    Address     string `xml:"address,attr"`
    Company     string `xml:"company,attr"`
}

func main() {

    // Open our xmlFile
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("info.xml")
    // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened info.xml")


    // defer the closing of our xmlFile so that we can parse it later on
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

    // we initialize our Users array
    var results ZIPResult
    // we unmarshal our byteArray which contains our
    // xmlFiles content into 'results' which we defined above
    err = xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &results)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(results.ADDRESSValue)
}
```

**info.xml**

```
<ZIP_result>
    <result name="ZipSearchXML"/>
    <result version="1.01"/>
    <result request_url="http%3A%2F%2Fzip.cgis.biz%2Fxml%2Fzip.php%3Fzn%3D1310045"/>
    <result request_zip_num="1310045"/>
    <result request_zip_version="none"/>
    <result result_code="1"/>
    <result result_zip_num="1310045"/>
    <result result_zip_version="0"/>
    <result result_values_count="1"/>
    <ADDRESS_value>
        <value state_kana="トウキョウト"/>
        <value city_kana="スミダク"/>
        <value address_kana="オシアゲ"/>
        <value company_kana="none"/>
        <value state="東京都"/>
        <value city="墨田区"/>
        <value address="押上"/>
        <value company="none"/>
    </ADDRESS_value>
</ZIP_result>
```

Comment: Hi, when answering question you should provide some explanation of what you did and why.

Comment: @dificilcoder 
Thanks! This code is easy to read.